# Как в каталог добавить сортировку по PREVIEW_PICTURE?

Tags: битрикс

Доброго времени суток 
Как добавить в каталог сортировку по наличию фото? т.е. сначала эл-ты с фото+сортировка по имени, потом без фото с сотрировкой по имени

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации такого варианта Вам понадобится использовать один из двух способов:

1. Создать свойство инфоблока которому присваивать значение в зависимости от наличия фото. Затем при подключении компонента передавайте это поле в один из параметров `ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD`.
2. Меняйте значение штатного поля сортировки в зависимости от наличия фото у товара.

Какой способ выбрать дело Ваше, главное это действие повесить на агента, который будет выполнять проверку элементов на наличие фото и менять значение поля сортировки/свойства в зависимости от наличия фото у товара.